# How to read value of a variable JSON field

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a JSON object like `[{'123':{'ID':'123','name':'abc'}}]` .
How to read name field.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: FYI this is JavaScript, not JSON. At any rate, try this in a JavaScript console: `const a = [{'123':{'ID':'123','name':'abc'}}]; console.log(a[0]['123'].name);`

Comment: You do not understood my question, suppose we do not know the ID that is if I am having 100 objects like this then how I can iterate through it to read name.

Comment: You're right; there was no way to know that you had "100 objects like this." Anyway, someone closed your question. Did the duplicate answer help you?

Comment: No It did not helped me.

Comment: Bummer. Well your best bet is to write a new question and be very specific that you have a list of items. In the example show more than one item in the list. Show exactly the list you are given and exactly what you expect in return.

Comment: Happy to help, feel free to let me know where the new question is if you don't get an answer.

Comment: Thank you Sir, I will share my question with you.